# SQL Server query where not in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

**Jobs**

```
    JobId
    StartDate
    RehireDate
```

**Paperwork**

```
    PaperworkId
    DocumentName
```

**JobPaperwork**

```
    JobId
    PaperworkId
    Completed
```

I need to find any jobs where a document has NOT been assigned to it that has a certain document name. I'm not sure how to construct this query. Using `NOT IN` doesn't work because it returns every job since it's finding jobs with other paperwork assigned to them.

Here's what I started with:

```
select j.jobid 
from Job j 
inner join JobPaperwork jp on j.JobId = jp.JobID 
where j.startdate > dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) 
  and j.rehiredate is not null 
  and jp.PaperworkID not in (select paperworkid 
                             from Paperwork 
                             where documentname like '%searchterm%')
```

Comment: it should be possible with NOT IN or NOT EXISTS - if you're looking for a document with a specific name then it shouldn't return paperwork which isn't that document. Show us your NOT IN attempt as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select j.jobid 
from Job j 
inner join JobPaperwork jp on j.JobId = jp.JobID 
where j.startdate > dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) 
and j.rehiredate is not null 
and NOT EXISTS ( select 1 
                 from Paperwork pw 
                 where jp.PaperworkID = pw.paperworkid
                 and pw.documentname like '%searchterm%'
                )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use NOT EXISTS statement, like this:

```
select j.jobid 
from Job j 
inner join JobPaperwork jp on j.JobId = jp.JobID 
where j.startdate > dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) 
and j.rehiredate is not null 
and jp.PaperworkID not exists (
select 1 
from Paperwork 
where 
documentname like '%searchterm%'
)
```

Comment: `and jp.PaperworkID not exists (` would be a syntax error and the `not exists` doesn't filter to the specific case in the query.